# Passing a Hub Context to a non Controller Class

Tags: c#, signalr

I am trying to send a message to a client in the server using SignalR

I am trying to do that in a class that is not a Controller. I have made the Startup like so:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.Configure<ConfigurationModel>(Configuration.GetSection("configurationModel"));

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseSignalR(routes => { routes.MapHub<MoveViewHub>("/movehub"); });
    }
}
```

In my Program, this one:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

This is in my Hub:

```
public class MoveViewHub : Hub
{
    private async void ReceiveTagNumber(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivedFromServer", sender.ToString());
    }

    public async Task MoveViewFromServer(float newX, float newY)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"Receive position from Server app: " + newX + "/"  + newY);
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceivedNewPosition", newX, newY);
        //await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivedNewPosition", newX, newY);
    }

    public async Task WriteThisMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceivedStatus", "Message was received. Thank you.");
    }

    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client has connected");
        RfidClass rfidClass = new RfidClass("THE HUB CONTEXT SHOULD BE HERE"); ====>> I NEED TO PASS MY HUBCONTEXT
        rfidClass.sas();
        RfidClass.SendTagNumber += ReceiveTagNumber;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), "Notepad++", @"notepad++.exe"));
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        Console.Write("Client has disconnected");
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

This is the RfidClass:

```
private IHubContext<MoveViewHub> hubContext;
public RfidClass(IHubContext<MoveViewHub> hubContext)
{
    this.hubContext = hubContext;
}

public void sas()
{
    Start();
}

private void Start()
{
    try
    {
        hubContext.Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceivedFromServer", "You are connected");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

How can I make it right?

Comment: can you please add services.AddDbContext<> to ConfigureServices and check, so that your DB context can be injected.

Comment: I need a hubcontext from signalR sir. not a db context.

Comment: Could you show us how you call your `RfidClass`? Explain how it works, if `RfidClass` is called by controller?

Comment: As soon as the Rfid Class is instantiated, I just want it to start then send a message that says you are connected. I call it on the OnConnectedAsync.

Comment: Check my answer @Ibanez1408

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inject `IServiceProvider` into your `Hub` by .NET Core DI (like into standard Controller, injecting by constructor):

```
public class MoveViewHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider

    public MovieViewHub(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
    public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client has connected");

        // you need to inject service provider to your hub, then get hub context from
        // registered services
        using (var scope = this.provider.CreateScope())
        {
            // get instance of hub from service provider
            var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var hub = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<MoveViewHub>>

            // pass hub to class constructor
            RfidClass rfidClass = new RfidClass(hub)
            rfidClass.sas();
            RfidClass.SendTagNumber += ReceiveTagNumber;
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), "Notepad++", @"notepad++.exe"));
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If you just want to `SignalR` work, you dont need to work on `Hub`. Instead make service. In this service inject `HubContext<>` of your `Hub`:

```
    // you need to make your own class and interface and inject hub context
    public interface ISignalRService
    {
        Task SendMessageToAll(string message);
    }

    public class SignalRService : ISignalRService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<YourHub> hubContext;

        public SignalRService (IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
        {
            this.hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public async Task SendMessageToAll(string message)
        {
            await this.hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReciveMessage", message);
        }
    }
```

Then register that service in your `Startup` class:

```
services.AddScoped<ISignalRService, SignalRService>();
```

After that you can call `SignalRService` wherever you want to like normal service from .NetCore DI container:

```
private readonly ISignalRService notificationService;


public SomeController(ISignalRService notificationService)
{
    this.notificationService = notificationService;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Send()
{
    await this.notificationService.SendMessageToAll("message");
    return Ok();
}
```

You dont need to make some work around like `RfidClass`.

Comment: Sir, when you said ...then get hub context from registered services, How do you do that? Can you give me an example. Thank you.

Comment: i pasted solution from your snippet. It not working? You need to call `IServiceProvider `in your `MovieViewHub`

Comment: You want to have `HubContext` in your `RfidClass` or just use `SignalR` in proper way?

Comment: Thank you Sir. This did it.